# Add a subsection to TOC without having titles appear in body

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to give additional information in the table of contents, but not have that information appear as a section title in the body of the document. Is there a way to manually insert entries in the TOC?

In the example below, I'd like the "subsubsection"s called "Diet" and "Migration" to appear in my table of contents, but not to appear in the document itself (so that "Often, people. No Need" is listed under the subsection "Brown", and there is no interruption with section titles).

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Bears}
They're large.

\subsection{Brown}
Also called Grizzly.

\subsubsection*{Diet}
Often, people.

\subsubsection*{Migration}
No need.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Diet}` at the appropriate place.